# Creating an Array of JButton

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton

Basically I am trying to make a Lightout game! I want to make an array of JButtons 
so I can keep track of the index of each of them (the reason being the state of each button is dependant on the state of the others)

so far I have:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    setTitle("Memory");
    setContentPane(panel);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));


    JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[5][5] ;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
          buttons[i][j] = new JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
        }
```

But this isnt working how I expect it to. I just got a big blank JFrame when I run this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where did you add all these `buttons` to frame in your code

Comment: I was under the impression that           buttons[i][j] = new JButton(); was the way to add buttons? Im really sorry, I'm kinda a noob at this

Comment: @Elchapo your for loop is bad .how much time you call pack and setvisible

Comment: @FastSnail Thanks! Ive fixed it

Comment: @Elchapo that's why it's discourage to omit curly brackets in for loop. there is a higher change to make a mistake .so use curly brackets to wrap if blocks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The attached code should fix it. You were creating button, but not adding it to the JFrame. I have edited the code to add action listener which accesses the id of the JButton and displays it , when you click it.

```
public class CodeSample extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8134989438964195251L;

public CodeSample() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    setTitle("Memory");
    setContentPane(panel);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));
    ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();

    JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[5][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
            buttons[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);
            buttons[i][j].putClientProperty("id",
                    String.valueOf(i).concat(String.valueOf(j)));
            buttons[i][j].addActionListener(listener);
            panel.add(buttons[i][j]);
        }
    }

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

public static class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(((JButton) e.getSource())
                .getClientProperty("id"));
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new CodeSample();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! that makes sense now! just to be clear, this definitely had to be a Matrix array correct? and the button at index [0][0] is going to be top left button?

Comment: @Elchapo yes that`s right [0][0]  is going to be top left button. The can be implemented in multiple ways. Matrix array is a good choice for this case.

Comment: This implementation is a matrix, but JButton (like any object) need not necessarily be stored in a two-dimensional array. One could also have a one-dimensional array of buttons.

Comment: @ingrid Thanks a bunch! I can set the background on the buttons with buttons[i][j].setBackground(color.black); correct? (Im on a mac if that makes a difference..)

Comment: @Elchapo spot on. You can add back ground by calling buttons[i][j].setBackground(color.black);

Comment: @ingrid Is there a method for finding which button is pressed? I have my  action listener set up and implements, and I know its working, I just need to differentiate which buttons are being pressed. Can I say something like buttons[this][this] ?

Comment: @Elchapo I have edited the code to assign a unique identifier for each button. When you click the button the unique id of the button is displayed on your ide console.

Comment: @ingrid I literally cant thank you enough! Thanks again!